# Cannot render component when sending object property via props

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Everything works below

```
const test = {
  title: "test title"
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p>{test.title}</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

But if I try to render a `Test` component that receives `title` props from `test.title` like below

```
const test = {
  title: "test title"
};

const Test = (title) => {
  return (
    <article>
      <h4>{title}</h4>
    </article>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <p>{test.title}</p>
      <Test title={test.title} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I get the error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: you need to destructure the title props `const Test = ({title}) => {`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are embedding `title` which is an object in expression that's why it shows

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

You can either destructure `title` or directly use `props.title` in the JSX

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-leftpad-6k67i?file=/src/App.js)

```
const Test = (props) => {
  return (
    <article>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </article>
  );
};
```

or

```
const Test = ({ title }) => {
  return (
    <article>
      <h4>{ title }</h4>
    </article>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Props are passed as `object` into component, so your title is in `props.title`

```
const Test = (props) => {
 return (
    <article>
      <h4>{props.title}</h4>
    </article>)};
```

Answer (score 0):

when try to send props as an Object one should destruct the object or directly use props.title